# How to disable refresh button from browser's menu bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

How to disable refresh Button From browser's menu bar using either angularjs or javascript or jquery

Comment: why you want to do that?

Comment: Please use the [tag:angularjs] tag instead.

Comment: Why I want this operation because, I am developing an application for online examination. so refresh option should not visible to student

Answer (score 5):

```js
function disableF5(e) { if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 116) e.preventDefault(); };
$(document).on("keydown", disableF5);

// simply visual, let's you know when the correct iframe is selected
$(window).on("focus", function(e) {
    $("html, body").css({ background: "#FFF", color: "#000" })
    .find("h2").html("THIS BOX NOW HAS FOCUS<br />F5 should not work.");
})
.on("blur", function(e) {
    $("html, body").css({ background: "", color: "" })
    .find("h2").html("CLICK HERE TO GIVE THIS BOX FOCUS BEFORE PRESSING F5");
});
```

```css
html, body { background: #000; color: #FFF; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; }
div { display: table; height: 100%; width: 100%; }
h2 { display: table-cell; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <h2>CLICK HERE TO GIVE THIS BOX FOCUS BEFORE PRESSING F5</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: This code is worked only when focus is in the box.You can not disabled the browser refresh button.